# Elf from a previous multiverse (D&D Lore)

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, content-identification, planescape

A few years back I remember reading on a Dungeons and Dragons related wiki about an elf who was a survivor for the previous multiverse/universe, but couldn't find it when I looked for it recently.

I seem to recall she was related to the Forgotten Realms or Planescape (which might be mistaken), looked really old, and had white hair. The closest I could find was Pharasma from Pathfinder/Golorian lore, but I don't think that was it. Anyway, maybe I'm misremembering, but if anyone knows who I'm talking about I would appreciate the information, because it's kind of driving me nuts.

Answer (score 8):

You’re thinking of the leShay, elf-like fey creatures that are said to predate the multiverse entirely, having somehow survived the destruction of a previous multiverse. Very, very little has been written about them, but you can find them in the 3rd edition *Epic Level Handbook*,¹ as well as the 4th edition “Realmslore: Sarifal” article in *Dragon* vol. 376.²

1. <sub>Which means their 3.*x* stats are open-game content and can be found [here for example](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/monsters/leshay.htm). Their lore, however, is not included.</sub>
2. <sub>The Sarifal article defines the leShay only as “the last scions of the once-great progenitor race of fey,” describes their rule of the city of Karador, and tells us absolutely nothing else about them. They do not get stats, and the only leShay who gets a name is High Lady Ordalf, despite *Forgotten Realms Campaign Guide* calling her an eladrin.</sub>